# White background when I never make that style

Tags: html, css, styles, frontend

First of all, sorry for my english, Isn't the better. Now... My question, programming a web page, I have a little problem with one div, like in the tittle, I put that div in the center, and the I set the width to the 90 percent of the page, but the 10% of rest, have a white background. I am trying to fix that during one day, but I don't have good results. Thank you so much to all the answers^^.

[The bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zQRB.jpg)

The part of the HTML:-

```
 <div class="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex velit voluptas, minus voluptatum accusantium fuga fugiat cum itaque molestias culpa, quos repudiandae nesciunt alias eligendi accusamus odio, ab delectus reprehenderit.
        </p>
    </div>
```

That is the part of the css:-

```
.content{
width: 90%;
background-color: #202020;
color: white;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

}

One thing more, that bug is present in all new tag that I add. I tried erasing all the color rules in the css and writing again, but doesn´t work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: There's a good chance that your `content` class would be better off being [a `<main>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default background colour of the `body` element is `white`.

Since `.content` is only `90%` wide, you can see the `body` behind it.

Style the `body`, or put an element around the `.content` and style that, or don't make the `.content` only 90% wide.

Comment: That fix the problem. Thank you so much, but one last thing... What element can i add to the both sides of the .content? a ::after and one ::before can fix that?